# How can i prevent of displaying the previous data in html-input?

Tags: jsp, forms, html-input

Hi I'm a Newbie in the field of HTML and jsp. as of now i was able to create a questioner website that connect to the database. but i have a problem when i try to review my questioner, the previous data are keep displaying when ever i type the first letter of my answer..

```
<input style="width: 100%" type="text" name="<%=rs.getString("number")%>-<%=i%>" value=""/>
```

how can i prevent this? any answer is appreciated. thanks in advance.
I'm sorry in my english..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `autocomplete` property on your HTML input tags:

```
<input style="width: 100%" type="text" name="<%=rs.getString("number")%>-<%=i%>" value="" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: Great!  Please 'accept' my answer as your chosen answer and welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

**Definition and Usage**

The `autocomplete attribute` specifies whether or not an input field should have autocomplete enabled.

Autocomplete allows the browser to predict the value. When a user starts to type in a field, the browser should display options to fill in the field, based on earlier typed values.

Note: The autocomplete attribute works with the following

```
<input> types: text, search, url, tel, email, password, datepickers, range, and color.
```

Syntax - `<input autocomplete="on|off">`

**on**   =>   **Default**. Specifies that autocomplete is on (enabled)

**off**  => Specifies that autocomplete is off (disabled)